# How do I view the invoices for a specific account through a URL in Microsoft Dynamics CRM?

Tags: forms, iframe, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to add an iframe into the form for viewing accounts that will display all the invoices that are connected to that account. I've read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx) MSDN page about accessing specific forms through a URL, which I can achieve, but copying the URL generated into an iframe I have created on my form produces an error message.

I'd like to know whether what I'm trying to accomplish is possible and if so, how I should format the URL so that only the invoices connected to the user account being opened will be displayed. I'll add more details later if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you actually want to do is add a sub-grid. This is different from an iFrame, an iFrame generally contains web resources, or links to pages on the web. A sub-grid specifically exists to show related records - e.g. to show the left hand relationships links on the body of the form.

[I think this article should show you what to do.](http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2010/10/form-sub-grids-in-dynamics-crm-2011.html)

Edit - based on Jacks comment:

So Crm can't handle this situation quite so easily with out of the box features. But you do have a couple of options. I dont think any of these are perfect solutions, so I'll let you choose.

1. A sub-grid effectively just runs some FetchXml, you can change this FetchXml with JavaScript, so you could alter the view to return the records not directly related. [Green Bible](http://crmgreenbible.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/crm-2011-change-subgrid-fetchxml.html) has an example, though this doesnt look like its supported.
2. Use a report in an iFrame.
3. Use a plugin, I havnt done this myself, but a colleague told me it was possible to stick a plugin on the retrieve message and basically change the query or results which is used by the view.
4. Create a second relationship between the invoice and the account. Then whenever you link an invoice to an account, also populate this new relationship (a workflow will do) with the account, and whenever an invoice linked to a contact is created, populate the new relationship with the parent account of the contact (again a workflow will do). Then just base your sub-grid on this new relationship. This approach isnt the cleanest but its probably the quickest and easiest to implement.

Comment: Thanks, this helps alot. It also highlights another problem. Some invoices are assigned directly to the account, while some are assigned to individual contacts who are then assigned to the account. Would it be possible to display both the account invoices and the related contact invoices on one subgrid?